# confusion of pip versions on MacOS 13.3

Tags: python, pip

I've updated my MacOS from a lower version to 13.3.

Now, I only have `Python3` on my OS(the update program deleted the old `Python2` which is a legacy from the old version of the OS).

[image]

However, I found I have two pips installed.

[image]

The two instances have the same version, 23.0.1, and they are not symlinks to each other.

Should I delete one of them? I am worried that it will cause problems when installing packages. I am not sure which one should I use in a certain circumstance.

Comment: They are probably still linked to the same python installation.
Don't manually delete individual binaries installed by your OS. use `python -m pip` instead of `pip` or `pip3` to make sure to always use the one associated with your `python` interpreter